# Rails Installation Error in ubantu12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I have already installed Ruby 1.9.3,gem 1.8.24, using RVM in ubantu 12.04. But when I instll rails using gem using command 
`gem install rails` ,
 then rails is installed with following message:
`Successfully installed rails-3.2.6

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.6...`
But when I check the version of rails then following error occur
`The program 'rails' is currently not installed. 
 You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails`


 I need help. Thank you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
gem install rails
```

Then run `rails -v`

Comment: First you run `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems`. Edit your profile settings (.bashrc OR .bash_profile)
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

and source the file:

`source ~/.bashrc`  OR `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Which line of text are replaced by which line of text?

Comment: I have following line of text at bottom in .bashrc
 file: PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14171/discussion-between-shamith-c-and-ganesh-kunwar)

Answer (score 0):

First try with

```
 rvm list
```

to get all ruby version then run following cmd to set one of ruby as default

First you have to set

```
 rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Then try cmd

```
 rails -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
run this command

```
source /etc/profile
```

Then, run rails -v